# .NET 4.5 SslStream - Cancel a asynchronous read/write call?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, sslstream

Is there any way to cancel a asynchronous read or write task on a SslStream? I have tried providing ReadAsync with a CancellationToken but it doesnt appear to work. When the following code reaches it's timeout (the Task.Delay), it calls cancel on the CancellationTokenSource which *should* cancel the read task, returns a error to the calling method, and the calling method eventually tries to read again, which raises a "The BeginRead method cannot be called when another write operation is pending" exception.

In my specific application I could work around this by closeing the socket and reconnecting, but there is a high overhead associated with reestablishing the connection so it is less than ideal.

```
    private async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, DateTime timeout)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        if (socket.Poll(Convert.ToInt32(timeout.RemainingTimeout().TotalMilliseconds) * 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) == true)
        {
            Task<int> readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            if (await Task.WhenAny(readTask, Task.Delay(timeout.RemainingTimeout())) == readTask)
                return readTask.Result;
            else
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the doc for `SslStream`, it does not support `ReadAsync` (it simply uses the fallback synchronous implementation from `Stream`). Since SslStream is a decorator Stream, is isn't obvious how to safely recover from a timeout on the underlying Stream, and the only obvious way would be to re-initialize the entire Stream pipeline. However given that the underlying stream might not be seekable, again this might not be idea.

For support of cancellation, the stream would have to override `Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32, CancellationToken)`. In the documentation, neither `NetworkStream` nor `SslStream` overrides the overload of `ReadAsync` required to consume cancellation (and `abstract Stream` couldn't possibly implement generic cancellation). For an example where cancellation IS supported, see [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) and contrast how the documentation differs.

So for a concrete case, if we were decorating `HttpStream` using `SslStream` then after a timeout we would want to recover by opening the `HttpStream` back at the position where we timed out (using the `Range` header). But there is no way to expose that generically using the `IO.Stream` class.

Finally you should consider what your failure case should be. Why would `ReadAsync` timeout? In the majority of cases I can think of, it should be due to unrecoverable network issues, which would necessitate the `Stream` being reinitialized.

Bonus point. Have you considered refactoring out your Timeout behaviour into a decorator Stream? You could then place the timeout decorator onto your underlying stream.

```
stream = new SslStream(
            new TimeoutStream(new FooStream(), Timespan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));
```

Comment: I'll look in to your TimeoutStream idea. To provide a bit more information, SslStream is "decorating" a NetworkStream obtained from a Socket. And it is timing out for a number of reasons, in my particular use it very well may not be because of unrecoverable network issues, so as I said it isnt ideal to reconnect.

Comment: Also where did you read that SslStream doesn't support ReadAsync? Looking at MSDN it says "Asynchronously reads a sequence of bytes from the current stream, advances the position within the stream by the number of bytes read, and monitors cancellation requests." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Matt See the reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/SecureProtocols/SslStream.cs
Sadly, there is no ReadAsync there, even in .NET 4.8. Fortunately, it looks like .NET Core (and .NET 5) does support it finally: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Net.Security/src/System/Net/Security/SslStream.cs